# Sorting a string and setting it

Tags: c, pointers

Note: this is homework

I need to sort a string and I'm not allowed to change method headers for this assignment.

I have filled in the method as follows (with an appropriate comparator):

```
void sortString(const char* input, char* output) {
    strcpy(output,input);
    qsort(output, strlen(output)+sizeof(char), sizeof(char),comparator);
    *output++ = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",output); //prints correct output
}
```

If I print output at the end, I see what I expect.

The method is called like so inside of a main function in a for loop:

```
char* key = malloc(strlen(words[i]) + sizeof(char));
sortString(words[i], key);
printf("key = %s\n", key); //key is blank
```

I don't understand how to get `key` to have the value of output.  From what I understand, I need to pass by reference, which would require sortString to take `char** output` so I could pass in `&key` but unfortunately I can't change method headers..  Is there another way to accomplish this that I am not aware of?

Comment: it is not necessary to pass a pointer to a pointer. Passing by reference means to pass a pointer, and String is already a pointer. So what you done is fine? what is problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sort induces undefined behavior. *(Unless the strings you are passing have two trailing null characters, which is unlikely. Also if your comparator sorts larger characters first then you won't have an issue either.)*

### What's going on here:

The issue is that we have a piece of memory that has these bytes in it:

```
{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0')
```

Your call to qsort will result in:

```
{'\0', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o'}
```

You then increment the output pointer, and then print `{'e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o'}`, which  **isn't null terminated**. This is undefined behavior.

Additionally though, after this call `key` points to `{'\0', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o'}`. The increment to the output pointer is not carried through because `output` is a local variable.

So when you try to print `key`, the first character of that string is a null character, meaning that it prints the empty string.

### Let's fix this:

```
void sortString(const char* input, char* output) {
    strcpy(output, input);
    qsort(output, strlen(output), sizeof(char), comparator);
}
```

Then to call this, we would do:

```
int main() {
    const char * words[] = {
        "hello",
    };

    char *key = malloc(strlen(words[0]) + 1);
    sortString(words[0], key);

    printf("%s -> %s\n", words[0], key);
}
```

### When would we need to pass `qsort(words[0], &key)`?

You only need to pass the pointer by a pointer (so a `char **`) if you were going to have `sortString()` allocate the memory for `dest`.

Comment: Hm what I was trying to do was allocate a string with 1 char extra and then stick the null terminator in there, but looking at it now, what I did was dumb. Thank you for the indepth explanation! This is very clear to me now.  For reference, my qsort is actually sorting smallest to largest (a->z), so would the null terminator be in the right place?

Comment: `qsort()` shouldn't move the null terminator in a correct version of this code. Your version in the question __does__ move it, which is where the undefined behavior comes from. If you note in the code I posted, the call to `qsort()` does not include the position in the string that includes `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The other way would be for `output` to point to a buffer big enough to hold the entire input string. Then you can copy the sorted string into that buffer. It looks like that is what you are already doing.